# Random Variable satisfying a property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Give an example of a random variable $X$ such that $X$ is equal in distribution to $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ where X and Y are iid but $X$ a.s. is not a constant.

Should X take an infinite number? No clue how to go about this one.

Comment: By "$X$ a.s. is not a constant" they almost surely mean that $X$ is a random variable which can take any one of multiple (finite) values. In other words, they just want to prevent you using the trivial case in which $X$ is just a number, rather than a "true" random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia ([Cauchy Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Properties/%22Cauchy%20Distribution%22))

> If $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, each with a standard Cauchy distribution, then the sample mean $( X_1  + . . . + X_n ) / n$ has the same standard Cauchy distribution.

The lack of moments of the Cauchy is what saves you here: the variance of the sample mean would have to be strictly less than that of the constituent random variables but for the Cauchy the variance is infinite so this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to be true $$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{X+Y}2\right)=\frac{\operatorname{var}(X)}2=\operatorname{var}(X)$$
But that would imply $\operatorname{var}(X)=0$, which in turn implies $X$ is a constant a.s.

But in this proof I have assumed that the variances exist. Look in to cauchy distribution where variance doesn't exist.

Comment: That;s true. But here we need to assume that X is not const. and show that the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Yes. For $X$ not constant, $X$ should follow a distribution for which variance doesn't exist. So I suggested cauchy distribution. The result in fact holds for standard cauchy.